# How to add Custom Css class to a footer block in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, blocks, css, footer

I want to attach one custom CSS class to a footer block using javascript. How can we do that?

```
<ul class="footer-links col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12"> 
<li><a href="/about-us">About Us</a></li> 
<li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Careers</a></li> 
<li><a href="/csmarketplace/account/login/">Sell</a></li> 
<li><a href="/terms-and-conditions">Terms & Conditions</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you want to add CSS class to a specific block or whole container?

Comment: @Sumit. Specific block i.e my custom footer block

Comment: Please add your block code here you've put in XML file.

Comment: <ul class="footer-links col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12">
<li><a href="/about-us">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
<li><a href="/csmarketplace/account/login/">Sell</a></li>
<li><a href="/terms-and-conditions">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
</ul>

Comment: Do you want to add CSS class on the ul element?

Comment: Can you please share the condition?

Comment: @Sumit See this https://prnt.sc/p6na8u I want to add css to this entire footer as marked in the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your screenshot, you can add your custom class in the footer block by copying `/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/footer.phtml` file in your theme with below content.

```
<div class="footer-container">
    <div class="footer">
        <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
        <p class="bugs"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Help Us Keep Magento Healthy') ?> - <a
            href="http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking"
            target="_blank"><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Report All Bugs') ?></strong></a>
        </p>
        <address><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getCopyright() ?></address>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

In `/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/templates/result.phtml` file in your theme add below content.

```
<?php
    $class = "";
    $searchProductCount = $block->getResultCount();
    if ($searchProductCount == 0) {
        $class = "custom_class";
    }
?>

<script>
    require([
       'jquery',
       'jquery/ui'
    ],function($){
       jQuery('.page-footer div.footer').addClass(<?= $class; ?>);
    });
</script>
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: My condition is if my serach for a particular product results nothing, i want to add class to the block. I am using /magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/templates/ result.phtml file. Is there any way to check in footer.phtml that when my search results with no products?

Comment: Thank you. I will try this

Comment: Getting this error Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result doesn't extends Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper

Comment: Again error https://prnt.sc/p6npam

Comment: OK, so we can't use the product collection count in the footer. I've added the code for the result.phtml file. You can try it.

Comment: Can u tell me where can i defined css class?

Comment: In $class = "custom_class"; variable

Comment: I tried and your solution worked well. Thank you. Accepting this ans